# <p> tag won't show in google chrome

Tags: php, html, css

I'm coding a website using HTML and CSS just for practice and i created a section on the right side of the page named "advert" with some CSS animation, I typed "advert" using "p" tag and for some reason, in chrome, it won't show but in firefox and in Microsoft browser, it does show up. can anyone please help me where's the problem lies?

[I typed "advert" using "p" tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnDLK.png)

[Chrome result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX4HC.png)

[Firefox result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEhK0.png)

Comment: Do not post codes as screenshot. Paste the codes in your question and format them.

Comment: Try using the `<span>` Tag

Comment: This is probably a error at your CSS code, paste the `#advert-text` CSS code here and let we see it

Comment: @LuísHNrique tried it, didn't work.

Comment: @LuísHNrique #advert-text {
  font-family:Secular One, architects daughter;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  position:relative;
  font-size:90px;
  top:90px;
  text-decoration:none;
  list-style-type:none;
  color:black; 
}

Comment: Try to set the same CSS on `#advert-link`

Comment: @aman tried it, it still didn't work and the funny thing is chrome won't even show "p" tag in inspect element but firefox and other browsers they do show  "p"  tag

Comment: Remove `p` tag and then check... write text without the tag

Comment: @aman it works without the text but I think there's something wrong with chrome, cuz I get the accurate result in other browsers e.g firefox and Microsoft edge.

Comment: No need to remove text only remove p tag e.g <a href="">Advert</a> and also use `-webkit-` for transform

Comment: @aman sorry I meant it works without the P tag. Yes, I do get the result without the p tag.

Comment: @aman but i don't think the problem's with the P tag, it's just Chrome that is not showing the result.

Comment: I posted a new Answer

Comment: @khulaid22 No need to do anything Just add  `display: inline-block;` in your CSS on `#advert-text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occours becouse of AddBlock, it blocks HTML elements with some especific words, `"advert-text"` is one of them.

Disable AddBlock and it will work. Its better just change the id of the element to prevent errors to another users.

In the exemple, if you are using adblock, the one with `id="advert-text"` doenst show up, but if you change the id it shows.

```css
#advert-text {
  font-family:Secular One, architects daughter;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  position:relative; font-size:90px;
  top:90px;
  text-decoration:none;
  list-style-type:none;
  color:black;
} 

#advert-test {
  font-family:Secular One, architects daughter;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  position:relative; font-size:90px;
  top:90px;
  text-decoration:none;
  list-style-type:none;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
id = advert-text
<p id="advert-text"> advert </p>
<br>

id = advert-test
<p id="advert-test"> advert </p>
```

Another exemple:

```html
Another exemple using span tag: <span id="advert-text">This may not be shown if you are using AddBlock</span> 
<br> <br>
But this one: <span id="anotehrId">This may be shown if you are using AddBlock</span>
```

Comment: it turns out the problem was because of adblocker, tried the same code but disabling the adblocker and it worked. I did like your previous answer a lot, will help me a lot in the future when I'll be coding a website. thank you again :)

Comment: for font names with space in `font-family`, you should surround it with quotes and provide at least 1 cross-system fallback fonts, such as `serif` or `sans-serif`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an adblocker installed in Chrome that hides elements that it suspects to be advertisements. Consider this example:

```html
<div id="advert-text">foo</div>
```

When I run this code with AdBlock Plus activated I cannot see the element. The CSS inspector shows me this rule injected into pages by ABP:

[image: AdBlock Plus hiding "ad like" elements]